# How do I handle an error after match function

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match

is there a way to handle an error in a loop
I use a match function to match a cottage with the right size and class as it is reserved. But if there is no cottage_size available, the match function returns an error, after which I want to upgrade the cottage(cottage_size=cottage_size+1) and search for a match again..
My question is how do i go back to the match function after the error and after I upgraded the size..

```
 If som = 0 And iDklasse = class And iDpers = cottage_size Then


                        Set klasseKolom = cottagesheet.UsedRange.Columns(3)
                        Set SizeKolom = cottagesheet.UsedRange.Columns(2)

                        For k = 4 To 1 Step -1
                            For p = 2 To 12

                                cottageId = (Evaluate("MATCH(1,(" & klasseKolom.Address(External:=True) & "=" & zoekklasse & ")*(" & SizeKolom.Address(External:=True) & "=" & cottage_size & "),0)"))
                                If Not IsError(cottageId) Then
                                huisnr = cottageId
                                    If Application.CountIf(validatorsheet.Range("B:B"), huisnr) = 0 Then                               'cottage beschikbaarheid (gaat niet goed)
                                        validatorsheet.Cells(iD, 2).Value = cottagesheet.Cells(cottageId, 1).Value                      'invullen in validatorsheet
                                        stay = Reservationsheet.Cells(iD, 3).Value
                                        arrival_date = Reservationsheet.Cells(iD, 2).Value
                                        For datumkolom = 2 To laatstekolom
                                            If arrival_date = roostersheet.Cells(1, datumkolom).Value Then
                                                 'If Application.CountBlank(Range(roostersheet.Cells(huisnr, datumkolom), roostersheet.Cells(huisnr, datumkolom + stay - 1))) = Range(roostersheet.Cells(huisnr, datumkolom), roostersheet.Cells(huisnr, datumkolom + stay - 1)).Cells.Count Then

                                                    Range(roostersheet.Cells(huisnr, datumkolom), roostersheet.Cells(huisnr, datumkolom + stay - 1)).Value = Reservationsheet.Cells(iD, 1).Value
                                                End If
                                            'End If
                                        Next datumkolom
                                    End If
                                ElseIf IsError(cottageId) Then zoekklasse = zoekklasse + k And cottage_size = cottage_size + p And klasseKolom = klasseKolom + k And SizeKolom = SizeKolom + p
                                                    cottageId = (Evaluate("MATCH(1,(" & klasseKolom.Address(External:=True) & "=" & zoekklasse & ")*(" & SizeKolom.Address(External:=True) & "=" & cottage_size & "),0)"))
                                                    huisnr = cottageId                  'indien er geen match is??
                                End If
                            Next p
                        Next k
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you not just put that same evaluate/match statement after the Then statement but with the `cottage_size + 1`? Just copy and paste it after Then and update accordingly

Comment: thought about that, but if there is still no match, it will return an error again (after which i would upgrade the class)

Comment: Would it be possible to loop that statement until no error appears?

Comment: that is my question :)

Comment: Maybe use [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) instead?  Much easier to catch if nothing is found.  Plenty of examples on here for its use.

Comment: how big is your range you are searching? Is it static or dynamic in size?

Comment: There is no `IfError` in VBA. `IsError` would work though, assuming `cottageId` is declared `As Variant`

Comment: oke thankyou, ill try the find function and isError. 
The range is static, +- 6000 rows, +- 100 columns and 4 sheets.

Comment: Hello, i tried the Find function but couldnt get it to work with the 2 conditions.. I tried it  like this (see code) but still get the same error

Answer (score 3):

Normally to run worksheet functions you would use the `WorksheetFunction` API.

Early-bound, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` gives you compile-time validation and idiomatic VBA runtime errors in case of mismatch (i.e. you can handle a mismatch with an `On Error` statement).

Late-bound, `Application.Match` loses compile-time validation, but now you get a `Variant/Error` result instead of a VBA runtime error in case of mismatch.

Using the late-bound version, you would have to validate that the result is usable before you consume it. The `IsError` standard library function returns true given a `Variant/Error` argument, so here:

> ```
> If IfError(cottageId) Then
>     '...
> End If
> ```

Try changing it to:

```
If IsError(cottageId) Then
    '...
End If
```

That makes your control flow look something like this:

```
For i = 1 To iterations
    Dim result As Variant
    result = Evaluate("complicated Excel formula string")
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        'TODO process valid result here
        Exit For 'we're done, no need to keep looping
    End If
Next
```

Consider heeding [Darren's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064526/how-do-i-handle-an-error-after-match-function#comment109772930_62064526) though: it does seem `Range.Find` could be a better tool here. Loop logic remains the same: last thing you want is to `GoTo`-jump and increment `i` until the counter overflows its data type - with a `For` loop you can cap the maximum number of attempts beyond which you just gotta admit that you didn't get a match for the given `cottage_size`; `Range.Find`/`Range.FindNext` have mechanisms that kind of already implement this for you.